# I can't get those posts from the wordpress to ionic

Tags: json

I'm facing a serious problem , I have to get some posts from wordpress website to my ionic app , so I activated the json api for wordpress but when I try to get specefic posts I can't find them in the json file.
this is the website
http://www.jneyne.com
and those are the posts(Dar Boumakhlouf,Dar Gaïa...)
http://www.jneyne.com/accommodation/

Answer (score 0):

The API endpoint for the post type 'accomodation' is `/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?type=accomodation`

Custom Post Types however are not shown in the API by default. You can enable this per Post Type by adding `show_in_rest' => true,` to the register_post_type arguments.

Documentation can be found [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-rest-api-support-for-custom-content-types/)

Comment: Thanks , I'm working with another JSON API plugin , it'll be the same work ? or I need to install the WP-JSON ?

Comment: Since there is an official Rest API for WordPress now I see no reason to ever use something else but I tried the code on your website and it worked so I'm pretty sure you are using the official WP Rest API

Comment: yes right , I'm using the official api , but I didn't understand where I must add the "show_in_rest' => true" ? in my ionic app code ?

Comment: The code should be added to the WordPress website that registers 'accomodation' as a Custom Post Type. Your Ionic app has nothing to do with this.

Comment: the problem that I can t get access to the website now because it s online , the admin said to me that I need to try this first on a local wordpress site to avoid bugs , so I have a a local wp site but I m not familiar with it , where can I found the "register_post_type arguments" ?

Comment: I just added a new post type on my local wp site , I added the post type on the functions.php ,  counter to my previous wp website , this time I can find the post data on the json file without adding the show_in_rest' => true

Answer (score 0):

Use [This Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rest-api-controller/)

It allows admins to toggle the visibility of, and customize the endpoints for, all custom post types within WordPress with an easy-to-use graphical interface.